# Error using pip install, I can't install any package

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5, conda

I'm using Python 3.5 and I am trying to install some packages. I usually use conda and everything's fine when I do but some packages is not in the anaconda repository and so I then use pip (either pip or pip3).

For some reason I get this error when I try to install any package not installed:

```
$ pip3 install pyqt3d
Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
req_to_install, finder)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 428, in _check_skip_installed
req_to_install, upgrade_allowed)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 728, in __init__
self.parsed = html5lib.parse(
AttributeError: module 'pip._vendor.html5lib' has no attribute 'parse'
```

I've seen some post with the same question but with inconclusive solutions. I am unfamiliar with pip/pip3 and rather scared of messing it up if I try to uninstall and install again. I still would rather use command line to install packages than manually installing with a .zip folder.

(I tried both on cmd and git bash)

Comment: What does `where pip` or `where pip3` say?

Comment: Respectively `C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe` and `C:\Users\MonsterIguan\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip3.exe`.

Comment: Try: `conda update conda` and later `conda update pip`.

Comment: This did the trick, after `conda update pip`. Any idea why I couldn't update pip through pip itself? Do I have to do `conda update pip3` as well?

Comment: `pip3` should work now too. Sometimes only conda works. I think this is fine as long as it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update conda:

```
conda update conda
```

then update pip with conda:

```
conda update pip
```

As a rule of thumb. Always use conda first before trying pip. That usually helps.